# g++7.2.0 fails auto non-type parameter deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, auto, non-type

I'm trying to use auto non-type parameter(c++17).
I expected that the 'Sample1::type' should be 'integral_constraint<int, 0>', but it was the same as 'Sample0::type'.

Is it g++ bug or my misunderstandings about the feature?
I use g++ (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3) 7.2.0 on Ubuntu 17.10.

```
-- auto_param.cxx --
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

template <auto V>
struct Value {
  using type = std::integral_constant<decltype(V), V>;
};

template <typename T>
auto demangle() {
  return boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<T>().pretty_name();
}

void zero_as_uint() {
  using Sample0 = Value<0u>;
  std::cout << __func__ << ": " << demangle<Sample0::type>() << std::endl;
}

void zero_as_int() {
  using Sample1 = Value<0>;
  std::cout << __func__ << ": " << demangle<Sample1::type>() << std::endl;
}

int main(int, char**) {
  zero_as_uint();
  zero_as_int();
  return 0;
}
-----------------------------
$ g++ -Wall -std=c++17 auto_param.cxx && ./a.out
zero_as_uint: std::integral_constant<unsigned int, 0u>
zero_as_int: std::integral_constant<unsigned int, 0u>
```

I found clang++ deduced as I expected.

```
$ clang++-5.0 -Wall -std=c++17 auto_param.cxx && ./a.out
zero_as_uint: std::integral_constant<unsigned int, 0u>
zero_as_int: std::integral_constant<int, 0>
```

Comment: Is template <auto T> a new way of saying T can be either a type or non-type? I'm used to seeing "class" or "typename" there

Comment: @Zebrafish Or, it must be a variable, You probably have seen `int` there, right? Well, here it's the same thing, just that the type is deduced.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79092

Comment: We shouldn't use this feature till gcc 8.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [bug in gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=79092). A further reduced example looks like this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <auto V>
struct Value {
  using type = std::integral_constant<decltype(V), V>;
};

static_assert(!std::is_same_v<Value<0u>::type, Value<0>::type>);
```

Those two types can't possibly be the same, as they refer to different template instantiations. It looks like gcc [has always had the bug](https://godbolt.org/g/YWHdz7), but it is fixed in the latest trunk.